# One Signal Google Play Services Library Error React-Native

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-services, onesignal, react-native-onesignal

I recently came across a problem with my app.

I had installed OneSignal, it worked. And some updates after adding the onesignal, stopped working. I don't know exactly what I did wrong or which module is conflicting with the onesignal, I've been on this problem for days and I still can't solve it. Need help.

[image]

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "smartial",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "android-linux": "npx react-native run-android --terminal \"$PWD/shkonsole\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^4.0.3",
    "react-native-onesignal": "^3.7.3",
    "@sentry/react-native": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-code-push": "^6.2.1",
    "react-native-google-places": "^3.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^2.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.12",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.4.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.6.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.12",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.8.0",
    "apisauce": "^1.1.1",
    "react-native-config": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-easy-app": "^1.7.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "@thallyssonklein/border-layout-react-native": "^1.0.14",
    "recoil": "github:eveningkid/Recoil#react-native",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.10.0",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    "eslint": "^7.1.0",
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

My android/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

My android/app/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: false,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smartial"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 24
        versionName "3.0.9"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('smartial-app.jks')
            storePassword KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
            keyAlias KEY_ALIAS
            keyPassword KEY_PASSWORD
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst "lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86/libc++_shared.so"
        pickFirst "lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so"
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.0.0'
    // implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6"
    // implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' //enter the latest version

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    implementation project(':react-native-config')
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal') // I just added this line 
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-code-push/android/codepush.gradle"
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <--- this should be the last line
```

My src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.smartial">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>


    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>

    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" tools:targetApi="28" tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning" />
</manifest>
```

Some observations:

- I checked the onesignal setup and followed all the steps again, nothing changed.
- I checked all the issues of this error, questions in the stackoverflow, I tried all the small solutions I could, nothing changed.
- I tried to remove the device directly on the onesignal panel and nothing changed.
- I ran both an avd and a real device, nothing has changed.
- I'm always running on debug, not on release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the app_id of the onesignal in the app to a new one and it worked.